Django Window-function Lag empty after filter()
I have a Django app where I maintain music charts. Each chart contains episodes with positions. An entry in the episode consists of a position and a track. Now, I want to display an episode from the chart along with all positions, as well as the position of the track in the previous and next episodes.
My models are structured as follows:

class Episode(models.Model):
    chart = models.ForeignKey(
        "Chart", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="episodes"
    )
    pub_date = models.DateField()

class Track(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField()
    title = models.CharField()

class Entry(models.Model):
    episode = models.ForeignKey(
        Episode, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="entries"
    )
    track = models.ForeignKey(
        Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="entries"
    )
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField()

My queryset looks like this:
window = {
    "partition_by": [F("track")],
    "order_by": [F("pub_date").asc()],
}

Entry.objects.filter(episode__chart=1).annotate(
    prev_position=Window(expression=Lag("position", 1), **window),
    next_position=Window(expression=Lead("position", 1), **window),
).filter(episode=3)


When I remove the filter(episode=3) part, I see filled prev_position and next_position, but when I add that last filter, the Window functions are no longer populated. What am I missing?
